# Chained Logic operator inside while loop error javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

If either of these two are true, i want to break out of the while loop. If either is not true, i want to re ask the question until they give a true answer. I am getting 'Type Error Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null' even though the variable is not null. I tried this in many different ways, cant get it to work. Please help, Thanks!

```
var newShape = prompt('shape please');

while(newShape.toLowerCase() !== "triangle" || newShape.toLowerCase() !== "square") {

    alert('no');
    newShape = prompt('shape please');

}
```

This works perfectly fine checking just one logic such as this example;

var newShape = prompt('shape please');

```
while(newShape.toLowerCase() !== "triangle") {

    alert('no');
    newShape = prompt('shape please');

}
```

I Would like to be able to add more logical operators

Comment: Why don't you think `newShape` is `null`?

Comment: "If either of these two are true, i want to break out of the while loop." - nope... think again.

Comment: Look at your condition again.  Aside from your property problem, this loop will never exit.  That condition will always be true.

Comment: If in the prompt, user writes 'triangle', if that is true, it should stop the while loop since i am checking for a !== right? Please elaborate on your comment. Thanks

Comment: If the user clicks on the `Cancel` button in the prompt, it returns `null`.

Comment: They marked my question wrongly as a duplicate and sabotaged my efforts to finding an answer to my question, what a shame smh